# Show unique count of specific values in column, groupby an additional column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to group by one column, reveal the counts of each unique value and display the proper column.

data

```
Id      location
e-db    ny
e-db    ny
e-db    ny
f-a     ny
f-a     ny
gr-x    ca
```

desired

```
Id      location    count
e-db    ny          3
f-a     ny          2
gr-x    ca          1
```

doing

```
df.groupby('location')['Id'].nunique()
```

However, this is not showing me the unique Id's and the actual value.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `df.groupby('Id')['location'].count()` ?

Comment: Hi thank you @ashkangh but its not bringing up the location

Comment: `df.groupby(['Id','location']).size().reset_index(name='count')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['location'] = df.groupby('Id')['location'].nth(0)
df2['count'] = df.groupby('Id').count()
```

Output:

```
Id  location    count
e-db    ny       3
f-a     ny       2
gr-x    ca       1
```